# Extended Vision changes ranged effects modifiers due to distance?

Tags: powers, vision-and-light, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm trying to build a character that has incredible powers of sight, using her Extended Senses (Vision). She uses firearms in battle. I kinda wanted to simulate her efficiency in shooting at great distances with ease, but I got stuck in some rules.

Ranged attacks have three ranges: short, medium and long, each one giving different modifiers based on the distance to hit the target.

> A ranged effect has a short range of (rank x 25 feet), a medium range
>   of (rank x 50 feet) and a long range of (rank x 100 feet). Ranged
>   attack checks at medium range suffer a –2 circumstance penalty, while
>   ranged attacks at long range suffer a –5 circumstance penalty.

Extended Vision would be a reasonable choice, but it seems to just affect Perception checks and not ranged attacks. I could use the Extended Distance Extra, but it seems that I would need to apply it to each weapon, or at least for a container of powers. Shouldn't Extended Vision affect the range for ranged attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As you note, extended senses just improve your ability to perceive things at a greater distance. It's still more difficult to hit something that's further away (scope wobble is magnified over distance, wind, bullet drop, more time for your target to have moved since you fired, etc) even if you can see them more clearly. You'd be looking at applying the Extended Range flat extra to double those ranges, and yes, you would apply it to each power, although the *Gadget Guides* and *Power Profiles* did introduce the idea of using Variable Descriptor to add an Extra to Equipment you wield, so that may work if your GM is cool with it.

Also, of course, the extended vision will make it easier to spot your target in the first place so that you can target their location, and it's possible that better visual acuity might negate other penalties the GM might otherwise apply.